# How do we call this optimization problem?

Tags: nonconvex-programming, minimax, bilevel-optimization

Let $f_k\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, $k=1,\dots,K$, be differentiable (possibly nonconvex) functions and $X\subset\Bbb R^n$ be a convex set.
Consider the following optimization problem:

$$
\min_{x\in X}\max_{k\in\{1,\dots,K\}} f_k(x).
$$

This is minimax problem but the inner optimization is a maximization discrete set.
Rather than a general minimax problem,  I guess this may be easier to deal with.
I am interested in the following things:

- Are there any papers which propose algorithms for such structured problem?
- Do the papers show non-asymptotic convergence analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your problem as \begin{align*}
\min y\\
\textrm{s.t. }y & \ge f_{k}(x)\quad k=1,\dots,K\\
x & \in X.
\end{align*}

What algorithms are applicable (and whether they converge in finitely many steps) will depend on the specifics of the $f_k()$ functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I investigate more detail properties of $f_k$ to ensure some good convergence results.